# Duda sobre ejercicio de PILAS en C

Tags: c, pilas, stack

el enunciado es el siguiente:
11. Suponiendo la existencia de una pila MODELO que no esté vacía, eliminar de la pila DADA todos los elementos que sean iguales al tope de la pila MODELO. 
Realice el siguiente codigo pero no logro dar con la consigna.

```
apilar(&MODELO, 5);
apilar(&MODELO, 3);
apilar(&MODELO, 8);
apilar(&MODELO, 2);

apilar(&DADA, 5);
apilar(&DADA, 3);
apilar(&DADA, 4);
apilar(&DADA, 2);
```

```
while(!pilavacia(&MODELO)){

        if (tope(&MODELO) == tope(&DADA)){          //Si el tope de MODELO es igual al tope de DADA, apilamos en topesIguales, desapilamos DADA
            apilar(&topesIguales, desapilar(&DADA));
        }else {                                     //Sino apilamos aux, desapilamos MODELO
            apilar(&aux, desapilar(&MODELO));
        }
    }
```

Solo se me vacia MODELO y el unico tope que pasa es el primero

Comment: ¿Cómo pretendes borrar elementos comunes entre `MODELO` y `DADA` sin bucle alguno?

Comment: Pero como lo harias vos?

Comment: Tal y como he dicho: con un bucle.